# replace groups in regex loop

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-group

I have these 2 lines:

```
What is P(output1|cause1=2, cause2=2)
What is P(output2|cause3=2)
```

I would like to change it to:

```
method_to_use(model, {"cause1": 2, "cause2": 2}, "output1")
method_to_use(model, {"cause3": 2}, "output2")
```

this is my regex:

```
.*P[(]([a-z1-9]+)[|](([a-z1-9]+)=([1-9]),?)+[)]
```

and I try to replace it like this:

```
method_to_use(model, {"$3": $4}, "$1")
```

but I only get the last fit of the group:

```
method_to_use(model, {"cause2": 2}, "output1")
```

is it possible to do some kind of a "loop" and change all fits on the way?

Comment: What is the programming language/tool?

Comment: the tool is sublime

Comment: 1) Replace `.*P\(` with `method_to_use(`, 2) `\(\K(\w+)\|([^()]+)` with `model, {$2}, "$1"`, 3) `(\w+)=(\w+)` with `"$1": $2`. One thing is certain: you can't do that with a single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the string with the following regular expression.

```
^.*P\(([^|]+)\|([^=]+)=(\d+)(?:, +([^=]+)=(\d+))?\)$
```

If capture group 4 is non-empty replace the (whole-string) match with

```
method_to_use(model, {"$2": $3, "$4": $5}, "$1")
```

This causes the string

```
What is P(output1|cause1=2, cause2=2)
```

to be replaced with

```
method_to_use(model, {"cause1": 2, "cause2": 2}, "output1")
```

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/q0wfkJ/1/)

If capture group 4 is empty replace the match with

```
method_to_use(model, {"$2": $3}, "$1")
```

This causes the string

```
What is P(output2|cause3=2)
```

to be replaced with

```
method_to_use(model, {"cause3": 2}, "output2")
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jBEN6t/1/)

Note that the regular expressions at the two links are equivalent, the only difference is that at Demo 1 I expressed the regex in *free-spacing mode*, which permits it to be self-documenting.

Instead of replacing the entire string one could of course simply form the new string from the values of the capture groups. If that is done `^.*P` at the beginning of the regex could be changed to simply `P`.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^             # match beginning of line
.*P\(         # match 0+ chars then '|('      
([^|]+)       # save 1+ chars except '|' in cap grp 1 (output)    
\|            # match ':'
([^=]+)       # save 1+ chars except '=' in cap grp 2 (causeA)
=             # match '='
(\d+)         # save 1+ digits in cap grp 3 (causeAval)
(?:           # begin non-cap grp
  ,\ +        # match ',' then 1+ spaces
  ([^=]+)     # match 1+ chars except '=' in cap grp 4 (causeB)   
  =           # match '='
  (\d+)       # match 1+ digits in cap grp 5 (causeBval)
)?            # end non-cap grp and make it optional  
\)            # match ')'
$             # match end of line
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is certain: you can't do that with a single regex.

You may use a 3-step  approach:

- Replace `.*P\(` with `method_to_use(`
- Replace `\(\K(\w+)\|([^()]+)` with `model, {$2}, "$1"`
- Replace `(\w+)=(\w+)` with `"$1": $2`

Note that

- `.*P\(` matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and the `P(`
- `\(\K(\w+)\|([^()]+)` matches `(`, then discards it from the match value with `\K`, and then 1+ word chars are captured into Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern), `|` is matched and then 1+ chars other than `)` and `(` are captured into Group 2 (`$2`)
- `(\w+)=(\w+)` - 1+ word chars are captured into Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern), `=` is matched and then 1+ word chars are captured into Group 2 (`$2`).